# How to show an image from other server into network using webclient and credentials?

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient, networkcredentials

I have an exception when I run my winform. In this procedure's got the exception:

```
public static byte[] my_image(string filename)
{
    byte[] imageByte = null;
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user_news", "41307Snd");
        imageByte = client.DownloadData(@"\\192.168.1.148" + @filename);
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
    }
    return imageByte;
}
```

It says WebException Username or pasword are not correct. I have in other server foldes(192.168.1.148) with images. What would be the problem?. Thanks in advance.

After that i realized when I enter by windows + R, put the ip and write my credentiañs in the windows that appears, my applications runs ok. I don't think that I did those steps all the time.

Comment: maybe the folder you are trying to get files from does not have access granted to the user's credentials.

Comment: What is at `\\192.168.1.148` ?  That's a UNC path not an HTTP URL

Comment: 192.168.1.148 is the server that contains the images. It is in the same network.